# Check for the root layout xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an xml file where I have found that container used is constraint layout so this constraint layout is called root layout or root layout can be different in android xml.

I want to know how to find the root layout and how can I give the id to that Layout? Can anybody explain the concept of Root Layout?

Comment: are u using viewBinding?

Comment: Giving an id to the root layout is the same as giving id to any other layout/view

Comment: @SarathSiva : Yes I am using viewBinding.

Comment: @Zain: ok understood. But how to find the root Layout?

Comment: just use binding.root

Comment: @Harry , I posted an answer, check and see  if that's what u looking for

Comment: Just add id in the xml to the root layout and use binding.my_root_id

Answer (score 0):

I am using viewBinding

```
lateinitvar binding:ActivityMainBinding

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // here binding.root is the root layout
}
```

Comment: This I have used but I just want to see that in xml file what should be the root layout?